# How to include get() and set() functions inside computed function using composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to include get() and set() functions inside the computed method using Composition API. However, this is possible using an option API like this.

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  computed: {
    colorCode: {
        get(){

        },
        set(){
            
        }
    }
  },
};
```

Is there any way to do this same task with Composition API? Really appreciate if somebody can help me in this situation, I was trying like this,

```
setup() {
    const colorCodeGet = computed(() => {
      return $store.state.colorCode;
    });

    const colorCodeSet = computed(() => {});

    return { colorCode };
  },
```

Comment: Read the fine manual. It should be expected that `computed` has a signature that matches this feature. It actually does, https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/171#issuecomment-895616971), You can do it like this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed, WritableComputedRef } from 'vue';

interface IBook {
  name: string;
  author: string;
}

class Book implements IBook {
  name: string;
  author: string;

  constructor(name, author) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
  }
}

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const book: WritableComputedRef<IBook> = computed({
      get(): IBook {
        return bookTakenFromSomePlace;
      },
      set(newBook: IBook): void {
        bookOldValue = new Book(newBook.name, newBook.author);
      },
    });

    return {
      book,
    };
  }
});
</script>
```